# Fixing SwipeRight - JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am having a difficult time using the `swiperight` function in JQueryMobile.  My issue is that when I assign it to a div:

```
$(".leftSide").swiperight(function() {
        alert("Working");
});
```

It is really hard to activate the swiperight using my finger on my android device.  If I use it on my computer screen using my mouse it works fine.

My main page is zoomed in by `170%` on an device and my dimensions are for the `.leftSide` div are: `125px x 50px`

How can I make this work better?  Am I doing something wrong?

All I want is the `swiperight` function so I made a custom download and only supply the `custom.min file` (I don't want any of the css or image work).

Suggestions, Thoughts?

Comment: swipe should trigger after 30px of drag in 1 sec or less. you can reduce those values if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys so after looking around I found a solution until JQuery fixes this issue to support Android Chrome.  Here is a plugin that I found that supports everything.

http://www.awwwards.com/touchswipe-a-jquery-plugin-for-touch-and-gesture-based-interaction.html

This works perfect on all browsers I have tried and all devices.  No delays or inconsistent results.

David